# How can I add oci8 PHP extension using cPanel

Tags: php, oracle, connection, hosting, cpanel

I'm sorry if this might be a newbie question.

I've bem trying to use oci_connect in PHP, but the folowing error returns:

> Call to undefined function oci_connect()

By doing some research I tried to add oci8 PHP extension using cPanel in order to solve this problem, but I haven't found a proper way to do it so, all the tutorials that I found appear to have acess to options in the cPanel not existent in my own.

The oly thing that appears being abble to add some type of oci8 package is the PHP PEAR Packeges, whit the package oci8 MDB2 driver, [link for repository](https://pear.php.net/package/MDB2_Driver_oci8/docs), but the instalation fails, besides that, the oci8 MDB2 driver appears to need PHP extension oci8 to be installed in the first place.

At the moment my company uses Hostgator as the host provider. Can someone idicates how to do this process in cPanel, or if there is some limitation in the particular case of cPanel/Hostgator.

Comment: The oci8 driver requires [Oracle Instant Client](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html) which (I believe) has a license that prevents redistribution, so you'll have to get the linked package from Oracle and then compile the oci8 module yourself with `pecl install oci8` or equivalent.

Comment: The license is designed to allow redistribution - but check the details of the license.